What is this Stardew Valley item?
The Trash Bear in Stardew Valley wants this bottle of something, but I can't figure out what it is:

Does anybody recognize this item? What is it?

That's Ginger Ale! 
It is prepared using either the kitchen inside an upgraded farmhouse or a Cookout Kit.

Lately I've seen users putting the items in their posts like they are emojis. How can I do this? (Even looking at the raw data through edit, I still don't understand)

@Alex I’m not sure, but I think it’s the [! before what you normally type in (and then an extra ] later)?

@Alex I just took the image from the game's wiki, and pasted it in the post like any other image. Nothing magical about it :)

Ahh! I should do that if I really need to. Thsanks.
